# Finding the most repeated character in a string in R

Tags: r

I have a string called "apple". I want to run a test to see which character has the most occurrence in the string, which is "p".

What I initially did was to use `str_extract_all("apple")`, and turn the list into a tibble, use `group_by()` and `summarise()` to return the most occurring character.

I would like to ask if there's an easier way to do this task? like maybe after extracting it out into a list, "a""p""p""l""e", I can instantly run a function to detect the character? Is there any package in `stringr` that does this job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using base R, we can separate every character and calculate their occurrence using `table` and return the one with max frequency.

```
most_repeated_character <- function(x) {
  tab <- table(strsplit(x, '')[[1]])
  names(tab)[tab == max(tab)]
}

most_repeated_character('apple')
#[1] "p"
most_repeated_character('potato')
#[1] "o" "t"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr/stringr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

x <- "apple"

x %>% 
  str_split("") %>% 
  table() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  filter(Freq == max(Freq))
#  . Freq
#1 p    2
```